# Testing compatibility for javascript 1.2

Tags: javascript, version, cross-browser

At work, We use a pretty old browser(symbol's pocket browser) that supports only JS 1.2. Deploying code to the test device running that browser is a bit painful. Is there any open source/free tool available that would allow me to check locally in a PC (running Windows XP/Firefox 3.6.8) whether the code written is compatible with JS 1.2?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using `<script language="JavaScript1.2">`.
Source: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch20_02.htm

Comment: Thanks. Haven't tested this feature yet with Fx. Will try this.

Comment: This feature isn't supported in Fx(ver 3.6.8 atleast). According to, http://bclary.com/2004/08/27/javascript-version-incompatibilities#notfriend ,they say mozilla would output the  difference but it didn't. Maybe older versions supported it, I guess.

Comment: That's not correct for most cases (at least the only one i tested :). `===` was introduced in 1.3, so `1 === "1"` should equal `false` on 1.2, and `true` (or syntax error?) on 1.2. if you run it on a modern firefox with that tag, you get `false`.